# Return Auto Increment value after inserting a record on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is the query that I have. In my Table User, the schemas is

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
        [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [UserFirstName] [nchar](33) NOT NULL,
        [UserSurname] [nchar](33) NOT NULL,
        [UserDob] [date] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [UserId] ASC
    )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What I wish to do is set the UserId automatically when I insert the userFirstName, userSurname and UserDob, when a new record is created.

I wish to use the userId that it generates in another table, what would the sqlserver syntax be for this.

I plan to call the above information from c# and asp.net

Comment: what type do SQL do you have ?

Comment: Use it for what? Usually `SELECT @NewUserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` is sufficient, but this won't work for multi-row inserts.

Comment: What's the other table? When are you inserting to it?

Comment: [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: look into using OUTPUT: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2829592/65223 in addition to doing to the original operation it can return a result set and insert into a different table simultaneously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Use SCOPE_IDENTITY not IDENTITY.

```
DECLARE @NewID int

INSERT INTO User ([UserFirstName], [UserSurname], [UserDob]) Values ('Bob', 'Smith', '1979-01-01')

Select @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


INSERT INTO OtherTable ([UserId]) Values (@NewID)
```

Comment: It is just `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, not `@@SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for bulk insertions suggest to use  `OUTPUT INSERTED`

```
CREATE TABLE #Ids
(
    Id INT
)


INSERT INTO [User] ([UserFirstName], [UserSurname], [UserDob])
OUTPUT INSERTED.UserId INTO #Ids
VALUES ('Bob', 'Smith', '1979-01-01'),
     ('john', 'will', '1979-01-01'),
     ('jerry', 'david', '1979-01-01')

INSERT INTO OtherTable ([UserId]) select Id from #Ids

drop TABLE #Ids
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create temp table variable and create a column called UserId.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(UserId INT)

INSERT INTO User ([UserFirstName], [UserSurname], [UserDob])
OUTPUT inserted.UserId INTO @TempTable
Values ('Bob', 'Smith', '1979-01-01')

SELECT UserId FROM @TempTable --Get the auto increment Id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't get multiple identities back as a result set. Your options are using a cursor and taking the identity for each row you insert, or store the identity before and after. Be sure to lock the table tho.

If it was me, and it wasn't time critical I'd go with a cursor.

Comment: Huh? The `OUTPUT` clause can certainly handle multiple inserts without relying on something very unreliable, like the identity value at the beginning and end of the transaction (do you really think the delta is guaranteed to be accurate?). Anyway the user doesn't even ask about multi-row inserts - I just happened to mention it in a comment, because I predicted an avalanche of "use @@IDENTITY / SCOPE_IDENTITY()" low-hanging fruit answers.